# port install mpeg4ip project failure

Tags: macports

I try to install mpeg4ip on macosx (Mojave) but failure:

```
sudo port install mpeg4ip
```

Error message:

```
--->  Building db48
Error: Failed to build db48: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_distfiles.macports.org_ports_databases_db48/db48/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port mpeg4ip failed
```

Is this project (mpeg4ip) still active? If not, how can install it!

Comment: I'm not familiar with mpeg4ip but your best option for support is to ask on the macports-users mailing list or to file a ticket in the bug tracker:  https://trac.macports.org

Comment: Till what I know `db48` is a stable port. Make sure you are using the latest stable version by `sudo port selfupdate`. In case it still fails, try enabling trace mode `sudo port -t install mpeg4ip`. Last resort would be to file a ticket as told by criag.